# how to share user session between subdomains?

Tags: django, session, subdomain, session-cookies, django-sessions

i have 1 website on `auth.mydomain.com`  and another as `home.mydomain.com`
i want to use `auth.mydomain.com` for authentication only and after authentication  user will get redirect to `home.mydomain.com`  with `auth.mydomain.com`  session cookie .

the whole idea is  i want to use `auth.mydomain.com`   to authenticate users from my all subdomains `*.mydomain.com`

in **Django** documentation i found `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` but i am not sure how to use it
documentation shows it shares cookie only if its authenticated with base domain like `mydomain.com`

anyone got idea how to solve this ??

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I've encountered the same issue?